# Whitespaces not escaped by /\s/

Tags: ruby, regex, whitespace

I'm working with some strings that behave in a strange manner.

Some whitespaces are not recognized by /s in a regex in ruby.

```
"175  75   16C  101/99    R".gsub( /\s/ , 'x' )
 => "175 x75  x16C x101/99   xR"
```

The expected result shoul be that every whitespace gets converted to 'x'

I tried to force encoding to UTF-8 to the string but it's not working either. I need a regex that matches every kind of whitespace in my string and converts them to regular whitespaces.

EDIT:

```
str.encode('utf-8').chars.each { |c| puts c.ord }     
49
55
53
160
32
55
53
160
160
32
49
54
67
160
32
49
48
49
47
57
57
160
160
160
32
82
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me: `"175xx75xxx16Cxx101/99xxxxR"`

Comment: I don't know Ruby, but you may try `\p{Z}` (all Unicode whitespaces). I don't know how Ruby handles `\s` compared to `\p{Z}`.

Comment: Please report the results of: 1) `str.gsub(/./) { |c| (c =~ /\s/ || !c.ascii_only?) 'x' : '' }` and 2) `str.encode('utf-8').chars.each { |c| puts c.ord }`, where `str = "175  75..."`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland c.ord gives me 160 for the strange whitespaces

Comment: @August, of course it works if you copy/paste from your browser...

Comment: @CarySwoveland, Lucas solution \p{Z} worked, in any case I'm still curious to know why

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski, you don't have to know Ruby to post a correct answer. :-) Please do so.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski, [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Regexp.html) is a reference you can use in your answer. Search that page for `\p{Z}`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks but a workaround is not an answer... I can't post an answer since I have no clue how Ruby handles Unicode in strings, what it includes in `\s`, and other subtleties. I'll leave that to someone who'll be able to provide a better answer than I could do.

Comment: @CarySwoveland actually, according to [regex-reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html), Ruby includes only ASCII whitespace in `\s`. This explains it all.

Comment: Thanks, @LucasTrzesniewski. Actually, I think most Rubyists know that. :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland I finally posted the answer, but was initially reluctant because I know some languages have their oddities with Unicode. Thanks for your input though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Ruby docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html), `\s` is shorthand for `[ \t\r\n\f]` (only a couple ASCII whitespace characters).

If your pattern includes other whitespace characters, such as non-breaking spaces, you can replace `\s` with `\p{Z}`, which will look for the Unicode *Separator* character property and thus will match all [Unicode-defined whitespace characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode).

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand from the question is you want to convert all whitespace to x. Your current regex search only for ASCII `/[ \t\r\n\f]/` according to [Ruby Docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Regexp.html). To support Unicode you'll need to use the special Unicode identifier for whitespace characters `[[:space:]]`.

**Unicode Regex**

```
"175  75   16C  101/99    R".gsub(/[[:space:]]/ , 'x' )
"175xx75xxx16Cxx101/99xxxxR"
```

Comment: Oh i see what you mean, just woke up :D

Comment: from memory doesn't the `/[[:space:]]/` string find unicode spaces?

Comment: I believe you are correct about `[[:space]]`. [Here's a ref](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Regexp.html). I suggest you limit your answer to that. Note that applying that to the (ASCII) string you scrape off the screen is not a test.